# WordPress - empty line inserted before "get_template_part();"

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on loading a template part into my theme. The get_template_part(); function works the way it is supposed to be, but it always inserts an empty line before itself.

Here is how it looks in the firebug:

[image: Firebug view]

This is how it's coded in php:

[image: Server-side view]

This is the content of polecane.php, only one line:
[image: This is the content of polecane.php, only one line]

What might be the problem? I have to get rid of that empty line because it messes up my layout.

EDIT: This does **NOT** work:
`<div class="homepageright"><?php get_template_part('polecane'); ?></div>`

Comment: I'm thinking that in Notepad++, you have encoding set with BOM. Try seeing what your encoding in notepad++ is.

Comment: @DaveChen I just switched the BOM off, it still does not work.

Comment: @DaveChen I solved it, added an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. DaveChen's idea with BOM was good, I simply changed the charset for one file only, istead of doing it for both of them. Thank you, now it works.

Answer:
Set encoding to UTF-8 without BOM for every file involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="homepageright"><?php get_template_part('polecane'); ?></div>
```

Comment: @DaveChen Can I modify that?

Comment: @DaveChen Yes, I tried his solution, no effect. Refreshed the page, same situation.